How to generate list from table data
I am new in php and mysql. I'm trying to create a page that will retrieve data from a table that will be displayed as a list.
Sorry, I just started self-learning php and mysql. I'd really appreciate it if anyone can help speed up my learning.

This is the form (form.php) I have made and it is working.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>enter data</title>
<style type="text/css">
.db1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.db1 input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.db1 textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.db1 form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Data to Database</h1>
  <form class="db1" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="+639012345678" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email_address" id="emailAddress" placeholder="user@domain.com">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>


This is the form submit (confirm.php) confirmation:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <title>confirm page</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <center>
        <?php
 
        // servername => localhost
        // username => root
        // password => empty
        // database name => db1
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db1");
         
        // Check connection
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
         
        // Taking all 5 values from the form data(input)
        $first_name =  $_REQUEST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
        $phone_number = $_REQUEST['phone_number'];
        $email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'];
         
        // Performing insert query execution
        // here our table name aem_contacts
        $sql = "INSERT INTO aem_contacts VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$phone_number','$email_address')";
         
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "<h3>Submitted successfully</h3>"; 
 
            echo nl2br("\n$first_name $last_name\n  +63 $phone_number\n $email_address");
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. "
                . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
         
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </center>
</body>
 
</html>


I wanted to create another page (list.php) that will display each time new set of data was entered from form.php., i.e.

Submitted Data:

First Name and Last Name 1
First Name and Last Name 2
First Name and Last Name 3


For your php you will need to connect to your DataBase,
this my php and html for when i search for something in my data and after finding it, it shows it
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "1234";
$dbname = "inventaire";

try {
    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
    $connexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo "Erreur de connexion: " . $error->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$resultatRecherche = null;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['txtModeleRecherche'])) {
    $modeleRecherche = $_POST['txtModeleRecherche'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM voitures WHERE modele = :modele";
    $stmt = $connexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':modele', $modeleRecherche, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $resultatRecherche = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        $resultatRecherche = false;
    }
}

$connexion = null;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>Recherche de voiture</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Recherche de voiture</h1>

<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="txtModeleRecherche">Modèle:</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtModeleRecherche" id="txtModeleRecherche" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Recherche" />
    </div>
</form>

<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $resultatRecherche): ?>
    <h2>Détails de la voiture</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="txtFabricant">Fabricant:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtFabricant" id="txtFabricant" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($resultatRecherche['Fabricant']); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="txtModele">Modèle:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtModele" id="txtModele" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($resultatRecherche['Modele']); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="txtCouleur">Couleur:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtCouleur" id="txtCouleur" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($resultatRecherche['Couleur']); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="txtPrix">Prix:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtPrix" id="txtPrix" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($resultatRecherche['Prix']); ?>" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Modifier" />
        </div>
    </form>
<?php elseif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"): ?>
    <p>Aucune voiture trouvée !</p>
<?php endif; ?>
[enter image description here][1]
</body>
</html>

I have put a result of what it shows

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Thank you! It works and I kinda got a hang of it.
This is what I came up with:
[conn.php]

[index.php]

